# Difference on index usage with following two queries?

Tags: sql, indexing

Let's say I want to find out if two columns have the same value, including the `null` value. If I have an index on both columns would it make any difference on index usage for the following two predicates?

```
WHERE (x=y OR x IS NULL AND y IS NULL)
```

or:

```
WHERE IFNULL(x, falseyValueForType)=IFNULL(y, falseyValueForType)
```

For example, for a numeric column, it would look like:

```
WHERE IFNULL(x,0) = IFNULL(y,0)
```

Comment: What **RDBMS** is this for? Indexing strategies and usage is **highly vendor-specific** - are you using `sql-server`, `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql` or something else entirely? Please add a relevant tag

Comment: `IFNULL` is a product specific function, but which vendor has it?